# Android emulator not working(black screen and offline) for open source project

Tags: android

I followed instructions [here](https://source.android.com/source/building) to build an open source android project(aosp-2.3.x).
After I finish building the project with:

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_arm-eng
make -j16
emulator
```

I can see a black screen emulator and two warning messages:

```
Could not automatically detect an ADB binary.
Some emulator functionality will not work until a custom path to ADB
is added in the extended settings page.

Running an x86 based Android Virtual Device (AVD) is 10x faster.
We strongly recommend creating a new AVD.
```

and in my terminal it shows:

```
 emulator: WARNING: system partition size adjusted to match image file (2050 MB > 200 MB)

emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
```

when I run `adb devices`, it shows:

```
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
emulator-5554   offline
```

The emulator works in Anroid Studio, but not from the terminal when I tried to build the open source android project, is there any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem like this, try to uninstall android phone driver (check on remove driver and restart pc) then go on search "universal adb driver", download and setup it, it works for me, hope for you too!

PS C:\Users\Nguyen\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools> adb devices
List of devices attached
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        device